# Rails 4 action routes with simple_form and shallow nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

```
resources :users, shallow: true do
    resources :shoes
end
```

This gives me two different routes for create and edit

```
user_shoes_path
shoes_path
```

In my shoes `_form.html.erb` if I leave the form tag :url as default I get a missing routes error when I submit a new or updated shoe.

If I supply the url in the form I can get it to work for either the new or the edit update, but I can't get it to work for both.

This works for the new:

```
<%= simple_form_for :shoe, url: user_shoes_path do |f| %>
```

This works for the edit, but will fail once it tries the actual update since it redirects to `/:param_id`:

```
<%= simple_form_for :shoe, url: shoes_path(@shoe) do |f| %>
```

How can I make it work for both? Thanks.

Comment: check the type of request that was sent in the 2nd form. It should be `PATCH/PUT`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should use

```
<% = simple_form_for [@user, @shoe] do |f| %>
```

and let do simple_form do the work...

This case, if there is a @user, simple form will use it (as for a new), if there isn't (like for an edit), simple form won't use it...

Comment: Danny its there a way to do this with form_for. I get the error on the edit part